# Post data using URLSession

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

When i try from `Alamofire` then it work fine but when i try to solve from `URLSESSION` Swift 4 then i got wrong response.
I checked in postman and it's response was right.

Parameter Description:
I have a key "data" whose value is another dictionary  `["answer1":"1","answer2":"2","answer3":"3"]`. Need to post this.

```
Wrong Reposnse = {"message = "Invalid data."; response = failure;}"
```

`Right Reposnse = {"response":"success","message":"Data Inserted”}`.

```
func postData()
{
    let BASEURLS = "http://sebamedretail.techizer.in/babystore_api/question_data"
    let parameter = ["data":["answer1":"1","answer2":"2","answer3":"3"]]
    let session = URLSession.shared
    var request = URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: BASEURLS)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    do
    {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:parameter, options: [])
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            do{
                let responseArr = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
    catch
    {}
}
```

Comment: `String(data:request.httpBody encoding:.utf8)`: Is that what you send in Postman?

Comment: I send data key inside this  i pass another key value pair to url

Comment: No i sent sent directly so postman giving response correctly

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems fine, maybe you should check the way you extract the JSON in your code, if it's PHP, here could be a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18867369/7452015

Comment: This is not my solutions